# Best framework for create responsive website?

Tags: responsive-design

I need much time for create a responsive website. Need to create normal website after it costumize the css using media query. I think I can safe my time. Sometime I browsing and find a framework : [amazium](http://www.amazium.co.uk/). My question,
Is the best framework or any another method for easily and fastly to create any responsive website? I need any suggestion for safe my time. Thank you.

Comment: "Best" by what criteria? [FAQ#dontask]

Comment: sorry, I'm new here and next I will read the police of this forum. But for now, Nick has solve my proble. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a framework like [Zurb Foundation 4](http://foundation.zurb.com/) it's a  responsive front-end framework highly recommended. It has *fluid layouts*, *responsive design* and a *grid system*.

- Getting started docs: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/
- Marakana TechTv video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HvE1h9gN8M

Comment: is Zurb support cross every browser (include I.E 6) ?

Comment: @user2272831 no it doesn't [docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/support.html)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your needs, but you should check out [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).

Answer (score 0):

[Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) would be my first choice.

Answer (score 0):

responsive website is not about the framework. Most of time is about how you organize your web page and how you use the framework.